# How does Class A remove the item from the list based on the behavior of class B?

Tags: c#, list, delegates

Question:

When a book borrowed, the Library will know **automatically** and
        remove it from the list.

Code (C#):

```
public class Library
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> BookList { get; set; }

    public Library()
    {
        BookList = new List<Book>();
        BookList.Add(new Book("HR"));
        BookList.Add(new Book("HR"));
        BookList.Add(new Book("Tiger"));
        BookList.Add(new Book("Lion"));
        BookList.Add(new Book("Elephant"));
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Book(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Hi I have spent a lot of time to solve this question but I have no idea at all.

Do I need to use delegate event? If I use delegate event, how Library can know which item to remove? 
I am not familiar with delegate. I googled around but I still can't understand how to use delegate in this question.

Or this question can be solved in other way without delegate or event?

Comment: What's the purpose of the animal class? Do your animals borrow books?

Comment: This question prolly assumes the Library has a 
"Borrow" method that handles this. Takes an instance of book as  parameter. Why does the constructor of Library take only one book?

Comment: @Sybren i have edited the question.

Comment: @user6144226 i have edited the question. I am thinking the same way. Is the question assume it has a Borrow method to handle it. If so, how does to let Library to remove the item from the Book class as they are different classes. Do I need static variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right way. Here is an Example how to solve your requiremtns with event and delegate:

```
public class Library
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> BookList { get; set; }

    public Library()
    {
        string[] books = new string[5] { "HR", "HR", "Tiger","Lion", "Elephant" };

        BookList = new List<Book>();

        foreach (string s in books) {
            Book b = new Book(s);
            b.borrowed += borrowed;
            BookList.Add(b);
        }
    }

    private void borrowed(Book b)
    {
        BookList.Remove(b);
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public delegate void BorrowedEventHandler(Book b);
    public event BorrowedEventHandler borrowed;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Book(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void borrow()
    {
        borrowed(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Decorator design pattern here: http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern.  Scroll down to the 'Real World code'.  I believe this will help without the requirement of a delegate.